# Get Active Directory ExtensionAttribute via UserPrincipal

Tags: c#, active-directory, derived-class

I am trying to get the value of user's `ExtensionAttribute4`.

This is my extension class to `UserPrincipal`:

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
{
    // Implement the constructor using the base class constructor. 
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
    { }

    // Implement the constructor with initialization parameters.    
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context,
                         string samAccountName,
                         string password,
                         bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
    { }

    // Create the "extensionAttribute4" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("extensionAttribute4")]
    public string ExtensionAttribute4
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("extensionAttribute4").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("extensionAttribute4")[0];
        }
        set { ExtensionSet("extensionAttribute4", value); }
    }

    public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, string identityValue)
    {
        return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityValue);
    }

    // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity. 
    public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, string identityValue)
    {
        return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityType, identityValue);
    }
}
```

Here is how I call the method:

```
 UserPrincipalEx user = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "someuser");
```

I see in debug that user really is result of `Classes.UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity`, but `extensionAttribute4` is not listed there. At all. Other attributes are there.

I tried to do the same with Manager, same result. The error is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I am new to this, so please excuse me if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for `ExtensionGet()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.extensionget) says that it returns "`null` if no attribute exists with that name". If the attribute is empty, it is considered as if it doesn't exist and it will return `null`. So you have to check for that.

```
[DirectoryProperty("extensionAttribute4")]
public string ExtensionAttribute4
{
    get
    {
        var extensionAttribute4 = ExtensionGet("extensionAttribute4");
        if (extensionAttribute4 == null || extensionAttribute4.Length != 1)
            return string.Empty;

        return (string)extensionAttribute4[0];
    }
    set { ExtensionSet("extensionAttribute4", value); }
}
```

Note that you can do the same thing without extending `UserPrincipal` by using [`GetUnderlyingObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.getunderlyingobject) and using the underlying `DirectoryEntry` object:

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "someuser");
var extensionAttribute4 = ((DirectoryEntry) user.GetUnderlyingObject())
                            .Properties["extensionAttribute4"]?.Value as string;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I just can't understand why it is not returning whole AD object. In PSH you just write get-aduser username -properties * and that's it...

Comment: Yeah, the `UserPrincipal` class doesn't expose all the attributes that exist in AD (even though it actually loads them all in the background). That's one reason I never use it anymore. I just use `DirectoryEntry` directly. It usually ends up being faster anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it next time, this "layers" are ridiculous. Much appreciated.

Comment: Indeed! `DirectoryEntry` itself is a layer over the native Windows [`ADSI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/ADSI/active-directory-service-interfaces-adsi).